# How can I fix the issue with accepting in-app Instagram user agreements when using Instagram API sharp in C#?

Tags: c#, instagram, instagram-api

im using instagram api sharp
when login to instagram ,i should accept in app [ this was me ]
How do I fix this problem?
and when follow the list of follower after 10 followed instagram It kicks out my account and app closed.
How do I fix this problem?

```
`private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            user = new UserSessionData();
            user.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
            user.Password = txtPassword.Text;
            ctx.api = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder()
                .SetUser(user)
                .UseLogger(new DebugLogger(LogLevel.Exceptions))
                .SetRequestDelay(RequestDelay.FromSeconds(0, 1))
                .Build();
            var loginRequest = await ctx.api.LoginAsync();      
        }
 private async void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
          foreach (string line in txtUser_UserName.Lines)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                //
                mseconds = random.Next(int.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text)) * 1000;
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
                var user = await ctx.api.UserProcessor.GetUserAsync(line);
               //for(int slep=0;slep>txtDirectUserName.Lines[20];slep++)
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(mseconds);
                var follow = await ctx.api.UserProcessor.FollowUserAsync(user.Value.Pk);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
                }
}`
```